# Why hasattr gives KeyError?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, keyerror, hasattr

```
chat = await Chat.objects.aget(chatid = chatid)
if hasattr(chat, 'agent') and 'active' in chat.status:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

This code throws `KeyError: 'agent'`.

In Python 3 hasattr uses try-except underneath so it shoudn't be a problem if attribute doesn't exist. So what could be possible reasons?

Full traceback:

```
[ERROR] Exception inside application: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 235, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
    return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'agent'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/security/websocket.py", line 37, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 24, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 116, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 50, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 194, in websocket_receive
    await self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "/chat/./chat/consumers.py", line 549, in receive
    if hasattr(chat, 'agent') and 'active' in chat.status:
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 253, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 216, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 643, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1926, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/chat/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Comment: Please include the *complete* error traceback matching the relevant code.

Comment: Added to main post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> `hasattr(object, name)`
>
> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is `True` if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, `False` if not. (This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an `AttributeError` or not.)
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr

See the last sentence. The object seems to implement a custom attribute getter, which raises `KeyError` instead of `AttributeError`.

Comment: Impressed with this answer!